# Visual Web Developer html button onclick event didn't fire

Tags: c#, visual-web-developer, vwdexpress

Below is my code:

default.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" 
    AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" 
    Inherits="TestAjax._Default" %>    

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">

    //I set an onClick event on this button:

    < input type = "button" id="btnCl" onclick = "doJob" />

</asp:Content>
```

default.aspx.cs:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //fires on page load;
}

void doJob()
{
    //code here;
}
```

The question is:

Why didn't the onclick event trigger? (On default.aspx btnCL)

Thanks

Comment: You probably want to use an `<Asp:Button>` so you get a server-side event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `dojob()` is a server-side function, but `onclick` on that `input` element is a client-side event.  You're probably getting an error in your JavaScript console saying that `dojob()` is an undefined function.

Use an `asp:Button` instead of an `input` to make use of server-side click events.  Also, `dojob()` should be `protected`.  By not declaring a protection level I think the default is `private` so the page controls might not even be able to see it.  It should match the event handler for a button click:

```
protected void dojob(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: So how do I use onclick event?

Comment: @user2191496: What do you mean?  Do you want to use a server-side event (which requires the page to post back to the server) or a client-side event (which you're currently trying to do)?  It's not clear what you're trying to do, so there's no clear answer on how to do it.

Comment: I am guessing he wants to make a server side call. I've added an answer showing how. The reason I think he wants server side is his code that he is trying to call is in the C# code-behind file and not JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an `asp:Button` control like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
```

and then have the event method like this:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // your code here
}
```

When using a regular `input` tag, `onclick` is for javascript, you have to instead use the ASP.NET control `asp:Button` in order to hook up the C# method.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in my comment in OP your current method is making a client-side call (so looking for a JavaScript function called `doJob`. You need to make a server-side call so need to use an `<asp:Button>` control. Some example of how you could achieve this:

**Web-Page (.aspx)**

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDoJob" Runat="server" Text="Do Job" OnClick="btnDoJob_Click" />
```

**Code-Behind (.CS)**

```
protected void btnDoJob_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do your action here...
}
```